# repetição de conteudo informado por meio de .html()

Tags: php, jquery

Informo por meio do JQUERY o link para abrir um video em um modal

```
<video width="100%" height="400" id="vid_video" controls="controls" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px">
<!-- AQUI DENTRO VAI O <source></source> vindo do JQUERY -->
</video>
```

JQUERY passa o caminho e o nome do video:

```
 $('#visualizarVideo').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
var vid_video = button.data('video') //captura o valor do data-video
$("#vid_video").html('<source src="../upload/'+vid_video+'" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
//vid_video recebe por exemplo video.mp4
```

beleza, está funcionando. Más tenho uma tabela com informações vindo do BD por um loop, e a cada linha da tabela é um vídeo diferente. Se eu clicar em um video e fechar logo em seguida, o próximo vídeo é o mesmo! Como se o jquery não implementasse o "data-video".
Espero que oque falei seja compreensível.

Dentro do loop informo por meio do data-video o endereço.

```
<li><a href="#" data-video="<?php echo $videos->vid_video ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#visualizarVideo" >Visualizar</a></li>
```

Obrigado pessoal! :)

Comment: O que vc está colocando na variável `button`?

Comment: Obrigado por responder sam. voce se refere: var vid_video = button.data('video') ? se sim, esta vindo dentro da <li> para armazenar onde ta o video.

Comment: Blz. Mas tinha que ver como você está atribuindo valor a variável `button`.

Comment: Ah entendi agora. desculpe. atualizei o codigo! da uma olhada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você trocar apenas o `source`, o navegador guarda em cache o primeiro vídeo rodado. O que você deve fazer é alterar a tag `video` toda.

`div` que irá receber o HTML:

```
<div id="vid_video"></div>
```

Evento:

```
$('#visualizarVideo').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
   var vid_video = button.data('video');
   var vid_html = '<video width="100%" height="400" controls="controls" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px">'
   +'<source src="'+vid_video+'" type="video/mp4"></source>'
   +'</video>';
   $("#vid_video").html(vid_html);
});
```

Comment: fenomenal sam. exatamente isso resolveu meu problema. muito obrigado! =)